# Inconsistent conditional result types with locals templatization

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, terraform

I have this code, which is working if I remove `version` from `msr` code block. But if I add it - this error pop-ups. I've tried so far to interpolate conditional and to change types of the variables. No luck

```
  mke_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        version: var.mke_version
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
        licenseFilePath: var.license_file_path
        upgradeFlags: [
          "--force-minimums",
          "--force-recent-backups",
        ]
      }
      mcr = {
        version: var.mcr_version
      }
      msr = {}
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }


  msr_launchpad_tmpl = {
    apiVersion = "API"
    kind       = "mke+msr"
    spec = {
      mke = {
        version: var.mke_version
        adminUsername = "admin"
        adminPassword = var.admin_password
        installFlags : [
          "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
          "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
        licenseFilePath: var.license_file_path
        upgradeFlags: [
          "--force-minimums",
          "--force-recent-backups",
        ]
      }
      mcr = {
        version: var.mcr_version
      }
      msr = {
        version: var.msr_version
        installFlags : [
          "--ucp-insecure-tls",
          "--dtr-external-url ${module.msrs.lb_dns_name}",
        ]
      }
      hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
    }
  }

  launchpad_tmpl = var.msr_count > 0 ? local.msr_launchpad_tmpl : local.mke_launchpad_tmpl
}
```

Expected behaviour:

To normally run plan and apply it and get the output at the end to change it for the launchpad and install everything by versions from this output which I can pass in `terraform.tfvars`

Actual behaviour:

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on main.tf line 179, in locals:
 179:   launchpad_tmpl = var.msr_count > 0 ? local.msr_launchpad_tmpl : local.mke_launchpad_tmpl
    |----------------
    | local.mke_launchpad_tmpl is object with 3 attributes
    | local.msr_launchpad_tmpl is object with 3 attributes

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a situation where Terraform doesn't really know how to explain the problem fully because the difference between your two result types is in some details in deeply nested attributes.

However, what Terraform is referring to here is that your `local.msr_launchpad_tmpl` and `local.make_launchpad_tmpl` values have different object types, because an object type in Terraform is defined by the attribute names and associated types and your `msr` attributes are not consistent across both objects.

One way you could make this work is to explicitly add the `msr` attributes to `local.msr_launchpad_tmpl` but set them to `null`, so that the object types will be compatible but the unneeded attributes will still be left without a specific value:

```
      msr = {
        version = null
        installFlags = null
      }
```

This difference in `msr`'s type was the only type difference I noticed between the two expressions, although I might have missed another example. If so, the general idea here is to make sure that both of the values have the same object structure, so that their types will be compatible with one another.

---

Terraform requires the true and false expressions in a conditional to have compatible types because it uses the common type as the return type for the conditional during type checking. However, in situations like this where you might *intentionally* want to use a different type for each case, you can use other language constructs that will allow Terraform to successfully complete type checking in other ways.

For example, if you combine both of those object values into a single object container then Terraform will be able to see that each of the two top-level attributes has a different type and see exactly what type each one has:

```
locals {
  launchpad_tmpls = 
    mke = {
      apiVersion = "API"
      kind       = "mke"
      spec = {
        mke = {
          version: var.mke_version
          adminUsername = "admin"
          adminPassword = var.admin_password
          installFlags : [
            "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
            "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
          ]
          licenseFilePath: var.license_file_path
          upgradeFlags: [
            "--force-minimums",
            "--force-recent-backups",
          ]
        }
        mcr = {
          version: var.mcr_version
        }
        msr = {}
        hosts = concat(local.managers, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
      }
    }
    msr = {
      apiVersion = "API"
      kind       = "mke+msr"
      spec = {
        mke = {
          version: var.mke_version
          adminUsername = "admin"
          adminPassword = var.admin_password
          installFlags : [
            "--default-node-orchestrator=kubernetes",
            "--san=${module.masters.lb_dns_name}",
          ]
          licenseFilePath: var.license_file_path
          upgradeFlags: [
            "--force-minimums",
            "--force-recent-backups",
          ]
        }
        mcr = {
          version: var.mcr_version
        }
        msr = {
          version: var.msr_version
          installFlags : [
            "--ucp-insecure-tls",
            "--dtr-external-url ${module.msrs.lb_dns_name}",
          ]
        }
        hosts = concat(local.managers, local.msrs, local.workers, local.windows_workers)
      }
    }
  }

  launchpad_tmpl = local.launchpad_tmpl[var.msr_count > 0 ? "msr" : "mke"]
}
```

Because Terraform can see the exact types of both `local.launchpad_tmpl["msr"]` and `local.launchpad_tmpl["mke"]` it will be able to determine the exact object type for `local.launchpad_tmpl` in each case, even though the two have different types.

There is one exception to this: if `var.msr_count` is unknown during planning (that is, if you've computed it based on a resource attribute that won't be known until the apply step) then Terraform will be left in a situation where it can't infer a specific type for `local.launchpad_tmpl`, and so Terraform will treat it as an "unknown value of unknown type", which effectively means that any uses you make of it elsewhere in the configuration won't be type checked during planning and so might fail at apply time. However, this caveat won't apply as long as `var.msr_count` is set to a static value you've specified directly in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I think that works for me with your kind of example. Mark as the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with TF 0.14 while trying to conditionally set replication_configuration in a call to aws_s3_bucket:

```
replication_configuration = var.replication ? local.replication_configuration : {}
```

var.replication was defined as a bool, and local.replication_configuration looked something like this:

```json
  replication_configuration = {
      role = "arn:aws:iam::${account}:role/${name}-s3-replication"
      rules = [
      {
        id     = "everything-without-filters"
        status = "Enabled" # Enabled or Disabled
        priority = 10
        delete_marker_replication_status = "Enabled"
        destination = {
          bucket        = "arn:aws:s3:::${name}-delete8-dr"
          storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Note: The contents of the json above are not real working code - they are provided only to illustrate the points below.

`{}` was not a close enough match to `local.replication_configuration` as it was defined, so the conditional failed, but the module for aws_s3_bucket errored when passed a null, so it was not possible to approach it this way, either.

Ultimately, I solved this by writing a conditional without using conditionals:

```
locals {
  repl_bool = {
    true = local.replication_configuration
    false = {}
  }
}

...

module "s3-bucket" {
...
replication_configuration = local.repl_bool[var.replication]
...
}
```

Writing code like the above really doesn't leave me with a good feeling. It looks awkward to me, and definitely has a hacky feel to it. But we needed to be able to write TF that only used one module, with or without replication, and this was a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error (`The given expressions are list and list`).

Took quite a bit of trial and error to figure another hacky workaround.

Here is a modified simple non-working example.

```
output "wont_work" {
  value = false ? {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: {
        baz: "foo",
      },
  } : {}
}
```

And here is my workaround

```
output "works" {
  value = try(false ? {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: {
        baz: "foo",
      },
  } : throw_error(), {})
}
```

When the condition is false,

```
value = try(false ? {        value = try(throw_error(), {})     value = {}
      foo: "foo",
      bar: {            ==>                                 ==>    
        baz: "foo",
      },
  } : throw_error(), {})
```